# How do you change the Collation of a column using Phinx

Tags: collation, phinx

I just started learning Phinx, and I am needing to change the collation of a column to latin1_swedish_ci. I'm not finding documentation on how to do this. I'm assuming it would be similar to:

```
->addColumn('text_two', 'string', ['collation' => 'latin1_swedish_ci'])
```

However, I have seen some talk that this feature wasn't implemented yet. https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx/issues/661

If anyone has any ways around this, that would be great!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature has been implemented as of [`0.7.0`](https://github.com/cakephp/phinx/commit/39e99f9db0ff6303d8079a70baf7f9e6a15d64f9).

To change the collation of an existing column `foo` in the table `bar` to `latin1_swedish_ci`, it would look like this:

```
$this->table('bar')
    ->changeColumn('foo', 'string', array(
        'collation' => 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    ))
    ->update();
```